# Making Constraint Layout Invisible based on Condition in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I'm using a condition that when if the statement is true, it will make the layout invisible or gone.
I have a Constraint layout named "courseLayout" and I am calling this layout in java doing this
`ConstraintLayout constraintLayout1 = findViewById(R.id.courseLayout);`
then in the if statement, I use
`constraintLayout1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`
It doesn't work and the app crashes for these lines. Is there any other way to call and operate on a constraint layout? What am I doing wrong?  Here is the Java code. the if statement works for other elements except on this constraint layout.

```
     
  ConstraintLayout constraintLayout1 = findViewById(R.id.courseLayout);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());

    
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        if(day==Calendar.FRIDAY){
        constraintLayout1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: can you show me the code what you've tried

Comment: Please post some code and the stacktrace

Comment: edited the post and added the java code. This is my first question tbh

Comment: Could you please add the crash log. and move the `ConstraintLayout constraintLayout1 = findViewById(R.id.courseLayout);` under `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: code doesn't give any error. When i open the app, it exits the app. cant find the crashlog

Comment: To find the crashlog click on `Logcat` at bottom of android studio then change `verbose` to `Error`

Comment: How about try to move the ConstraintLayout constraintLayout1 = findViewById(R.id.courseLayout); under setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConstraintLayout constraintLayout1 = findViewById(R.id.courseLayout);`

Your initializing view outside oncreate method its not the way you need to initialize view inside `onCreate()`

Comment: It Worked! to declare the variable publicly is what caused the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct answer :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout1 = findViewById(R.id.courseLayout);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        if(day==Calendar.FRIDAY){
        constraintLayout1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks. Correcte my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try to use *findViewById* inside *onCreate()*

```
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());


    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    if(day==Calendar.FRIDAY){
        constraintLayout1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Btw, you've forgotten to close the conditional statement with ***{ }*** after *constraintLayout1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);*

Comment: it worked. The bracket mistake happened in the post actually, there are more codes in the original java code.